# Regex to obtain strings in operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6, regex-group

I need to obtain the elements involved in an operation using regex with javascript. I know that these strings are limited to contain lowercase a-z characters, dots, underscore characters and numbers. I don't need to grab the elements around them like parenthesis, or division/multiplication symbols. As a rule of thumb, I know that all these elements contain at least a dot. For example:

- For `((my.metric.name_a-bc.test.metric)/(1000000-foo.bar.ab_cd))*100`, it should return `my.metric.name_a-bc.test.metric` and `1000000-foo.bar.ab_cd`
- For `100*another.metric.name.here` it should return `another.metric.name.here`
- For `this * -1` it should not return anything as none of the elements contain a dot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are sure, that all strings are valid, You can use something like this:

```js
const strings = [
  '((my.metric.name_a-bc.test.metric)/(1000000-foo.bar.ab_cd))*100',
  '100*another.metric.name.here',
  'this * -1'
];

const values = strings.flatMap((str) => str.match(/(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/ig))
```

[image]